# Are EF6 migrations supported on SAP HANA database?

Tags: .net, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations, hana

I need to know if it is possible to use the ef code first approach with migrations with a SAP HANA database.

This particular is very important because based on it we will decide to use this database or remain with the platform that we already used.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what EF codes are? That's certainly not a 'thing' that relates to a specific feature in SAP HANA.

Comment: @Mattia: How did it all end? Have you been able to use code first migrations with SAP HANA? Did you use SAP HANA 2 Express or what else?

Answer (score 0):

Trying to EF in SAP HANA 2.0. There is documentation about Entity Framework:
[link](https://help.sap.com/viewer/0eec0d68141541d1b07893a39944924e/2.0.00/en-US/ac86b96b98984a7e9b5a3e8194db39ea.html)

But in version 2.0.62 of SAP client libraries implementation EF Provider is not full. It generates NEWID insted of SYSUIID for example.

Comment: This documentation sucks. It refers to Visual Studio 2013 or even 2010 (sic!). I'm pretty curious if there is anybody, including author of the tutorial, who managed to complete it.